# IntelliJ does not show all the method for String Class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created a maven project Quickstart, I defined a

```
String as = "hello";
```

When I try to see methods for "as", it shows nothing in suggestions i.e.

```
as.length().
```

it shows nothing in suggestions, Same for

```
DesiredCapabilities cap  = new DesiredCapabilities();
```

cap does not find

```
setCapability("","")
```

I have tried to fix it but cant find a solution,, I tried mvn clean compile, mvn clean install, and many other things, I am using *IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2* .

I tried with both **Community** as well as **Ultimate** but no luck.

This is snapshot
[image: Java set]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting work? Does IntelliJ understand this is Java code? Do you have Java installed and does IntelliJ know where that is?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html

Comment: Please share an image of your intellij project. You are sure that the class is marked as java source

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I suppose Java is set as follow

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the JavaScript target to at least  ES2016. For that you need to set this parameter in TypeScript  configuration :

```
"target": "es2016",
```

in the file tsconfig.json, if you don't have it you need to generate it with:

tsc --init

this is in the root of your project